# Passing react function to children down, event.target empty

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to grasp a react concept that to me is likely used all the time.

I have an app with a state. 
I have a section below app. 
Below section I have clickable tile that receives a function to update app status. This works, however the event.target appears to be null.

I'm passing the function to update the status all the way down from app as a prop.

How can I fix this / what am I missing?

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const Section = ({ handleClick }) => {

  return (
    <div className="section">
      Section
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} title="1" />
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} title="2" />
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} title="3" />
    </div>
  )
}

const Tile = ({ handleClick, title }) => {

  return (
    <div className="tile" onClick={handleClick}>
      tile {title}
    </div>
  )
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false
    };
  }

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true,
      openedBy: ""
    })
  }

  closeModal = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false,
      openedBy: event.target.title

    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>ModalOpen = {this.state.modalOpen.toString()}</div>
        <div>Opened by = {this.state.openedBy}</div>
        <Section handleClick={this.openModal}></Section>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close modal</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks so much for pointer in the right direction!

Comment: You mean event.target.title is not printing ?

Comment: "the event.target appears to be null" did you mean `event.target.title`? Because `event.target` should be ok.

Comment: Also you are passing `number="1"` but expecting it to be a `{.... title }`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes I am expecting output from event.target.title

Comment: `event.target` will be DOM node that has not `title` attibute set. So your expectations are wrong :)

Comment: try currentTarget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing down a `title` prop to your `Tile` component, but your are passing down a `number` prop.

You can create a new function in the `Tile` component that calls the `handleClick` with the `number`, which you then use to set the `openedBy` in your `App`.

**Example**

```js
const Section = ({ handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="section">
      Section
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} number="1" />
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} number="2" />
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} number="3" />
    </div>
  );
};

const Tile = ({ handleClick, number }) => {
  return (
    <div className="tile" onClick={() => handleClick(number)}>
      tile {number}
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false,
      openedBy: ""
    };
  }

  openModal = title => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true,
      openedBy: title
    });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false,
      openedBy: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>ModalOpen = {this.state.modalOpen.toString()}</div>
        <div>Opened by = {this.state.openedBy}</div>
        <Section handleClick={this.openModal} />
        <a href="#" onClick={this.closeModal}>
          Close modal
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working perfectly fine :

```js
const Section = ({ handleClick }) => {

  return (
    <div className="section">
      Section
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} number="1" />
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} number="2" />
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} number="3" />
    </div>
  )
}

const Tile = ({ handleClick, title }) => {

  return (
    <div className="tile" onClick={handleClick}>
      tile {title}
    </div>
  )
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false
    };
  }

  openModal = event => {
    console.log(event.target)
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true,
      openedBy: ""
    })
  }

  closeModal = event => {
    console.log(event.target)
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false,
      openedBy: event.target.title

    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>ModalOpen = {this.state.modalOpen.toString()}</div>
        <div>Opened by = {this.state.openedBy}</div>
        <Section handleClick={this.openModal}></Section>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close modal</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

However I assume that you want to pass down the title of the clicked element back into the handler. If so, I recommend using a curried function, with 2 sets of parameters, and setting the title variable as the first one :

```
  openModal = title => event => {
    console.log('Opened by : ', title, event.target)
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true,
      openedBy: ""
    })
  }
```

Your `Tile` component can now indicate which title it has by calling the function the first time :

```
const Tile = ({ handleClick, title }) => {

  return (
    <div className="tile" onClick={handleClick(title)}>
      tile {title}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Working example :

```js
const Section = ({ handleClick }) => {

  return (
    <div className="section">
      Section
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} title="1" />
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} title="2" />
      <Tile handleClick={handleClick} title="3" />
    </div>
  )
}

const Tile = ({ handleClick, title }) => {

  return (
    <div className="tile" onClick={handleClick(title)}>
      tile {title}
    </div>
  )
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false
    };
  }

  openModal = title => event => {
    console.log('Opened by : ', title)
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true,
      openedBy: ""
    })
  }

  closeModal = event => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false,
      openedBy: event.target.title

    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>ModalOpen = {this.state.modalOpen.toString()}</div>
        <div>Opened by = {this.state.openedBy}</div>
        <Section handleClick={this.openModal}></Section>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close modal</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```